# How to print column names along with not null values in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file with 1500 columns where only some of the columns will have a value like below:

Emp|C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6|C7

ABC||Y|||X||A

DEF|A||Y||B||T

Output should be:

Emp Col_Name    Col_Value

ABC C2  Y

ABC C5  X

ABC C7  A

DEF C1  A

DEF C3  Y

DEF C5  B

DEF C6  T

Comment: did you try df.melt()？

Comment: ‘df=df.dropna(axis=1)’ then ‘print(df.columns)’

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlfow. Please read [ask] to understand how to write good questions :)

Comment: Thanks WeNYoBen. I used combination of melt and not null to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks WeNYoBen. I used combination of melt and not null to get the result.

df=pd.read_csv("test.csv")

newDf = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Emp'],var_name='Col_Name', value_name='Col_Value')

newDf = newDf[pd.notnull(newDf['Col_Value'])]